# Laravel : How to update data in one to one Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I have two tables:

```
 1. User.
 2. Post.
```

In post table i have saved the user information. So when I click on update, it should load the particular user data. It's get loaded but when i click on the save button to update save.It's showing the following Error.

> FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 78: Call to undefined
>   function App\Http\Controllers\fill()

I think i have problem with my postUpdate controller. But I couldn't find the problem.

Here is my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

     public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post'); //Profile is your profile model
    }
}
```

Here is my Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name','gender',                            'dob','nationality','nid','email','phone_no','about_me'
];
     public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //Profile is your profile model
    }
}
```

And here is my post Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class PostController extends Controller
{


   public function getDashboard()
   {        
     $posts = Post::all();
          return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts]);  
    }


  public function postCreate(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
      'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
      'middle_name'=> 'required|max:120',
      'last_name' => 'required|max:120',
      'gender'=> 'required',
      'dob'=>'required',
      'nationality'=>'required',
      'nid'=>'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'phone_no'=>'required',
      'about_me'=>'required',
        ]);

    $post = new Post();
        $post->first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $post->middle_name = $request['middle_name'];
        $post->last_name = $request['last_name'];
        $post->gender = $request['gender'];
        $post->dob = $request['dob'];
        $post->nationality = $request['nationality'];
        $post->nid = $request['nid'];
        $post->email = $request['email'];
        $post->phone_no = $request['phone_no'];
        $post->about_me = $request['about_me'];        
        $message='There was an Error';
        if( $request->user()->post()->save($post)){
          $message = "Profile Created successfully";
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => $message]);

  }


    public function postUpdate(Request $request)
    {
          $this->validate($request,[
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'middle_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'gender'=> 'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'nationality'=>'required',
            'nid'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone_no'=>'required',
            'about_me'=>'required',
            ]);


        $request->user()->post()->update(fill($request->all())) ;  

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you're getting a collection of posts:

```
$data=Post::all();
```

But you need to pass an array. Try to replace it with:

```
$data = $request->only('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'dob', 'nationality', 'nid', 'email', 'phone_no', 'about_me');
```